# PHP - How to check if the spelling of a string is correct or not? No “suggestions for misspelled words” needed. Just return plain true or false

Tags: php, dictionary

I have an array of strings generated randomly. Now, how am I going to check if a string is correctly spelled or not, based on US English dictionary. This way, I can remove non-English words from the list.

What I did right now is to loop through the list and have it queried to a database of dictionary words. Unfortunately, it is not efficient especially if my list contains hundred of words.

I have read about Aspell but unfortunately, I have to install it, and I am restricted because I am hosting the program in a shared web hosting.

Anyway, here's what I have so far:

```
//  generate random strings using the method I coded
//  returns a string array of generated strings
//  no duplicates generated here
//  just plain permutations
$generated_list = generate();
```

Since I have read an article that instead of looping and do query for each string, I just did a single query, like this [Performing A Query In A Loop](http://www.toptal.com/php/10-most-common-mistakes-php-programmers-make#common-mistake-4--performing-queries-in-a-loop) :

```
$only_english_list = [];
if (count($generated_list)) {
    $result = $connection->query("SELECT `word` FROM `us_eng` WHERE `word` IN (" . implode(',', $generated_list));
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        $only_english_list[] = $row['word'];
    }
}
```

However, is there more efficient in checking if a string is in English dictionary? Something like a method that will return true or false?

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju: He asked same question earlier (sometimes before) regarding this issue only. It was closed and get deleted by USER only. Again, he asked the same question with no code.

Comment: I just loop through the array and each string is being queried to a database table containing English words.

Comment: @NanaPartykar did knew that... anyhow, question will be closed again...

Comment: @LynnellEmmanuelNeri, we are here to help you out in your code, not to code...

Comment: huhuhu... I don't feel welcomed here in StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes, I will show portions of my code.

Comment: @LynnellEmmanuelNeri, sure.. add that... in any mistake, we will defenitely help you..

Comment: Some things you can do: Remove duplicates, create *one* query (the `IN` operator would be useful for that), and let the database do the work. Using a relational database would be slow pretty much no matter what you do. You would need an in-memory representation of the dictionary (a tree structure of some kind, or a hash table, for example) in order to make it fast.

Comment: @LynnellEmmanuelNeri No one wants you to feel unwelcome - however showing your code is a requirement, as it is not uncommon for people to simply expect SO users to do their work for them, Showing code proves you are genuinely trying to solve the problem but need help.

Comment: Hello. I've already added a code snippet.

Comment: Ok, adding code is a start. How does the sql query relate to your `$generated_list`? It seems to be unrelated.

Comment: I've updated the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now have an answer to this problem. Here's what I did. Instead of generating permutations, which takes a MASSIVE amount of time and resources, I just utilize IMMEDIATELY the capability of MySQL. That is, I used REGEXP or LIKE against a table of English words of a certain length.

So, for English words that can be formed from `vleoly`, I used this query to a table of English words of length 6, noted by `us_6`.

```
    SELECT word FROM us_6 WHERE
    word REGEXP 'v' AND
    word REGEXP 'l.*l' AND
    word REGEXP 'e' AND
    word REGEXP 'o' AND
    word REGEXP 'y'
```

And results generated are `lovely` and `volley`.

For more information, check [MySQL, REGEXP - Find Words Which Contain Only The Following Exact Letters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34521107/2589643)