# MySQL, REGEXP - Find Words Which Contain Only The Following Exact Letters

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a database of English words of a certain length. For example table `us_6` contains English words with length of 6.

Now, I want to search the table for words that contains only certain letters. For example, I want to search for words that contains letters `vleoyl`. I did the search using REGEXP. Here's my query:

```
    SELECT word FROM us_6 WHERE
    word REGEXP 'v' AND
    word REGEXP 'l' AND
    word REGEXP 'e' AND
    word REGEXP 'o' AND
    word REGEXP 'y' AND
    word REGEXP 'l'
```

The result returns correct words like `lovely` and `volley` but it also returns other words. Here's the result of the query:

```
    lovely
    loveys
    overly
    volley
```

Can you help me with this? I only want words that contains exactly the letters provide. For example, `vleoyl` should only return `lovely` and `volley`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Return matching pattern in REGEXP query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361457/mysql-return-matching-pattern-in-regexp-query)

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen, unfortunately, the question, though similar, but quite different.

Comment: My goal was to just point out one possible solution for matching. There are many other examples out there.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen, Thank you. I truly appreciate your effort. Sorry about that.

Comment: I don't think you should attempt this in SQL - but happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: @Strawberry, can you suggest what tool should I use? I chose MySQL because I have over thousands of words in a table and I find it the most efficient tool to handle searching hehe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you're checking for the presence of `l` twice. That's the same as... "It contains an `l`. Yep, still contains an `l`." It's not checking for two of them. Here's an alternative...

```
SELECT word FROM us_6 WHERE
word REGEXP 'v' AND
word REGEXP 'l.*l' AND
word REGEXP 'e' AND
word REGEXP 'o' AND
word REGEXP 'y'
```

This should match all words containing a `v`, two `l`'s, an `e`, an `o`, and a `y`.

So, every other occurrence of the same letter, just append another .*letter to the query. For example, `lullaby` needs the following query:

```
    SELECT word FROM us_7 WHERE
    word REGEXP 'l.*l.*l' AND
    word REGEXP 'u' AND
    word REGEXP 'a' AND
    word REGEXP 'b' AND
    word REGEXP 'y'
```

See how I add 3 `*.l` because there are 3 occurrences of `l` in the word `lullaby`.

The same thing can also be accomplished with `LIKE` instead of `REGEXP`. Here's an equivalent query for the original question...

```
SELECT word FROM us_6 WHERE
word LIKE '%v%' AND
word LIKE '%l%l%' AND
word LIKE '%e%' AND
word LIKE '%o%' AND
word LIKE '%y%'
```

Comment: So, if I have 4 v and 5 y, what would my query be like? By the way, I tried the query and it worked. Thumbs up.

Comment: Hey, I tried adding .*v to every occurrence of v and it worked. Wow. Can I edit your answer to append my findings, okay?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. To match 4 `v`'s, the pattern would be `'v.*v.*v.*v'`. The `.*` means zero or more of any character so it will match any string with at least 4 `v`'s in it regardless of whether or not there are characters in between them.

Comment: Sure, go for it. This isn't the most elegant solution, so I'd love to see a better one. Maybe there's an obscure MySQL built-in function I'm not aware of that would help with this.

Comment: Added an equivalent query using `LIKE` instead of `REGEXP`.

Comment: is there any possibility of utilizing your solution so that it can accommodate words that are less than the passed letters? For example, I am looking for 4 letters words that can be formed from `vleoly`. Notice that I am looking for 4-letter words out from the passed 6-letter word.

Comment: Hmm, good question. I'd have to think about that and it's probably worthy of its own question. :)

Comment: Okay, I'm going to create another question now. Would you standby with it as well? I am very grateful to you and the community :)

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look later.

Answer (score 3):

Think outside the box!

Store `lovely` and `volley` as `ellovy`.  That is, sort the letters, then do an exact match.

Build a table that maps

```
ellovy -> lovely
ellovy -> volley
ellowy -> yellow
elorvy -> overly
elovsy -> loveys
```

And have a non-`UNIQUE` (not `PRIMARY`) key on the first column.  (Probably have the second column be the `PRIMARY KEY`.

No need for `REGEXP`, `OR`, etc.  And muuuuuch faster.  Furthermore, it could be a single table for all word lengths.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seriously advocating this as a solution - instead I'd use application level code for this task (e.g. a bit of PHP), for which there must be myriad tutorials - but just for fun...

```
SELECT * FROM strings;
+-----------+--------+
| string_id | string |
+-----------+--------+
|         2 | lovely |
|         3 | volley |
|         1 | yellow |
+-----------+--------+

3 rows in set (0.00 sec)SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(a.x,b.x,c.x,d.x,e.x,f.x) needle
  FROM 
     ( SELECT 'v' x UNION ALL SELECT 'o' UNION ALL SELECT 'l' UNION ALL SELECT 'l' UNION ALL SELECT 'e' UNION ALL SELECT 'y') a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT 'v' x UNION ALL SELECT 'o' UNION ALL SELECT 'l' UNION ALL SELECT 'l' UNION ALL SELECT 'e' UNION ALL SELECT 'y') b
  JOIN
     ( SELECT 'v' x UNION ALL SELECT 'o' UNION ALL SELECT 'l' UNION ALL SELECT 'l' UNION ALL SELECT 'e' UNION ALL SELECT 'y') c
  JOIN
     ( SELECT 'v' x UNION ALL SELECT 'o' UNION ALL SELECT 'l' UNION ALL SELECT 'l' UNION ALL SELECT 'e' UNION ALL SELECT 'y') d
  JOIN
     ( SELECT 'v' x UNION ALL SELECT 'o' UNION ALL SELECT 'l' UNION ALL SELECT 'l' UNION ALL SELECT 'e' UNION ALL SELECT 'y') e
  JOIN
     ( SELECT 'v' x UNION ALL SELECT 'o' UNION ALL SELECT 'l' UNION ALL SELECT 'l' UNION ALL SELECT 'e' UNION ALL SELECT 'y') f
  JOIN strings s
    ON s.string = CONVERT(CONCAT(a.x,b.x,c.x,d.x,e.x,f.x) USING utf8) ;

+--------+
| needle |
+--------+
| lovely |
| volley |
+--------+
```